# how to hide a jquery accordion block

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

1 - I have a jquery accordion with 3 panels.

2- I need to hide, via js, any given panel.

3 - On the internet, i've found this script, it works very well for panels other than the first

```
$('#myAccord').accordion().children('.ui-accordion-header:eq(index)').hide();
```

If you use this script on the first panel, a truncated line appears.

Is there a way to handle all cases, included the first panel?

```
<div id="myAccord">                 
    <b><img src="img1.png">option1</b>                      
    <div id="data1"></div>

    <b><img src="img2.png">option2</b>                      
    <div id="data2"></div>

    <b><img src="img3.png">option3</b>                      
    <div id="data3"></div>
</div>

$("#myAccord" ).accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true
});
```

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like you want to learn how to do this rather than having an issue with some that you already built. Check out https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible to learn about accordion with jquery UI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is `.ui-accordion-header` only hides the header and not the div itself. Best bet will be to hide each element explicitly:

```
$('#myAccord').accordion().children('b:eq(index), div:eq(index)').hide();
```